# git rebase and squash the commit with a message

Tags: git

Is it possible when we resolve some git conflict via `git rebase` to  **squash** that rebase via simple message for example `"resolve conflicts"`.

This is my commit history after resolving a specific conflict:
[image]

As you see the last 3 commits represent a `git rebase` then `git push -f`. I think it's more logical to set just one commit with a message instead of having 3 (the number of commits on the current branch) commits

Comment: If I didn't misunderstood your question, what you want is git fixup.

Comment: I think so, thank you for your reply, could you explain to me the fixup command, and is it recommanded in my case ? What do you think when I should use it?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing an interactive rebase, picking the commits you want and the ones you want to squash you prefix with squash instead of pick.

For example in your case it would look something like this (the number is how many commits after HEAD you would like to rebase):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

You will then get a prompt with the commits and their message which will look something like this:

```
pick <HASHID> Initial Commit 
pick <HASHID> Login via mail instead of username
pick <HASHID> Add missing files
```

Just change the pick to squash (And keep one as the pick commit).

You will then be able to rewrite that commit message and voila you have 1 commit which you do git push -f if you would like.